# Save state of achievements in Angry Birds after deleting and re-installing app?

Tags: achievements, angry-birds

I want to delete Angry Birds from my phone, but keep my score and state, so that if i install it again later, and sign in, it will preserve my current achievements. Is that possible?

Comment: What platform? Android? iOS? Mac? PSN?

Comment: Really not sure about this one, but I think (on iOS) game center will keep your achievements (or you'll be prompted).

Comment: If you have an Android phone, this QA could help: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2432/how-to-backup-angry-birds-saves-data

Answer (score 3):

On iOS, the actual GameCenter achievements are stored on Apple's servers.  You don't need to back them up.  The progress is saved in `private/var/mobile/Applications/<Angry Birds>/Documents/highscores.lua`, so you can back up and restore that file.  [Here's easy instructions for it](http://www.iphonedownloadblog.com/2011/03/17/backup-iphone-game-progress/).

On Android there are no achievements but for backing up progress, [there's an app for that](https://market.android.com/details?id=fima.angry.backup).  If you have root, you can also manually back up `/data/data/com.rovio.angrybirds` or use an app like [Titanium Backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup).

I would expect similar options to be available for other platforms.  (See [How can I move my progress from one machine to another on Chrome Angry Birds?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22488/how-can-i-move-my-progress-from-one-machine-to-another-on-chrome-angry-birds) as well).

Answer (score 0):

if you have a PC try this little app http://birds-scores.en.softonic.com/