# How can I move my progress from one machine to another on Chrome Angry Birds?

Tags: angry-birds, google-chrome

I'm playing Google Chrome Birds http://chrome.angrybirds.com/ and how can I move my progress to one computer to another without playing all the levels again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try copying the following file from one computer to the other:

`C:\Documents and Settings\<your user account>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\http_chrome.angrybirds.com_0.localstorage`

<sub>(Change the drive letter as appropriate)</sub>

Backing up and restoring this file works for me on the same computer, but I'm not sure whether it can be transferred between Chrome installations (or whether more files are additionally required).

Comment: It worked, but it's lacking your username after Documents and Settings.

Comment: @Weslei Haha, that's because I used < and > without properly escaping them as `&lt;` and `&gt;` (so it was removed as an invalid HTML tag). Thanks for the catch!